# Does the mono runtime already handle tail call optimisation as required by the IL spec?

Tags: mono, runtime, il

I know that by this infamous post

http://flyingfrogblog.blogspot.com/2009/01/mono-does-not-support-tail-calls.html

the mono runtime did not offer tail call elimination as required by the IL. Has this changed since?

Comment: Should be simple to try this out. According to the comments on that page there shouldn't be problems with Mono.

Comment: Not willing to install mono and clobber my system. I am thinking about giving F# a try an Linux but will only do so if properly supported. I did not find any affirmative statement on the mailing list or blog that it should word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not yet. There's some work-in-progress on adding it, though : http://www.mail-archive.com/mono-devel-list@lists.ximian.com/msg24438.html (wish me luck ;-) ).

Comment: Good luck for your master thesis. Rewriting the calling convention as part of a thesis seems a very ambitious work. Maybe it is enough to improve the LLVM integration which already does "proper tail calls"?

Comment: LLVM unfortunately is too slow for short-running programs, and currently it's not likely to become the default.